# Views: Relationship with filtering?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a content type `shortcut` with the fields `field_namespace` and `field_active`. Additionally, I have a Taxonomy term vocabulary named `namespace` that is used in `field_namespace`.

Example content:

```
Title       | Namespace   | Active
------------+-------------+-------
Shortcut 1  | Namespace A | True
Shortcut 2  | Namespace A | False
Shortcut 3  | Namespace B | False
```

Now, I have a view displaying a list of these Taxonomy terms as a table. A column of this table display the number of Shortcuts tagged with the particular term. Example:

```
Namespace   | Shortcut count
------------+---------------
Namespace A | 2
Namespace B | 1
```

I built this using a Views Relationship with *Taxonomy term: Content with term*. I used this relationship to add the Field *Shortcut: Nid* with the Aggregation Type *COUNT DISTINCT*.

**What I now want:** The Shortcut count shall only consider Shortcuts whose `field_active` is True, i.e. the output shall be:

```
Namespace   | Shortcut count
------------+---------------
Namespace A | 1
Namespace B | 0
```

So the *COUNT DISTICT* aggregation shall be somehow filtered by the value in `field_active`.

Is there an UI way to do this? If not, which hook is appropriate to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having asked a friend, I can now answer the question myself.

The solution is pretty straightforward: At *FILTER CRITERIA*, I simply add `field_active`, with the operator "Is one of" checking the value "On".

I thought, *FILTER CRITERIA* may only be fields actually displayed, but this is not the case. It works for all fields being in any form used in the view.